# Web3 Rinkeby Infura Problems

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, ethereumjs, infura

I've got a Smart Contract that works perfectly when deployed to `localhost: 8545` (using `Ganache`) with my `Web3` Dapp. But when I put it on `Rinkeby`, I'm running into problems,.

The Contract is super-simple: all it does is let you Set and Get the value `uint` variable `x`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16; 


contract Incrementor { 

    uint x; 


    constructor() public { 
       // Give x in initial value of 10:
       x = 10; 
    } 


    function getX() external view returns (uint xValue) { 
        return (x); 
    } 


    function incrementX(uint byThisMuch) public { 
        x += byThisMuch; 
    } 


}
```

After running it successfully on `localhost: 8545` I've now deployed it to the `Rinkeby` TestNet (via `Remix`) and am using `Infura` to connect to it - but I'm suddenly experiencing inconsistent behavior there. Specifically, my `getX()` function works, but my setter `incrementX()` function gives me errors:

[image: accounts error]

Its basically not picking my address.

**NOTE:** this problem has been happening even **BEFORE** the Nov. 6 2018 `Metamask` update

Here's how I'm setting up `Web3` in my `HTML`:

```
if(typeof(web3) !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("Web3 provider found! Current Provider is WORKING!");
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        }
        else {
            console.log("1. NO Web3 provider found!  Gonna set one up...");

            // Connect to Infura:
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<MY API KEY"));

            // Or use this when connecting to `localhost`:
            // web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


            console.log("2. OK, NOW we DO have a PROVIDER --> HttpProvider = ", web3.providers.HttpProvider);

            web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts;
            console.log("3. ALL ACCOUNT - web3.eth.accounts = ", web3.eth.accounts);
            console.log("4. web3.eth.defaultAccount = ", web3.eth.defaultAccount);

            // Also tried with 'getAccounts' (same as `.accounts` - but asynchronous)
            console.log("5. web3.eth.getAccounts() ==> ", web3.eth.getAccounts());

            web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) { 
                if(error != null)
                    console.log("7. Error! ", error);
                else
                    console.log("7. Result = ", result);
            });

            console.log("Exiting the WEB3 JAM!");

        };
```

Again, refer to console log above to see what's happening.

What's strange is that I am ***definitely*** connecting and talking to the Smart Contract on `Rinkeby` - and I know this because my `getX()` button-click action **is** returning the right values:

[image: getter works]

But when I try to **set** it - *that's* when I get that error.

Really, its more about the fact that my address keeps coming back as `undefined` - which I think is the real issue here:

And here's a quick screen grab of what the App's interface looks like:

[image: DAPP Interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infura do not save your keys. When you were connected to your local node this worked as your local node have your accounts. You need to set your account manually by loading your keys. The reason why `getX` works is because the function is view and can be executed in Infura nodes without sending a transaction. `incrementX` change the contract state and therefore you need to submit a transaction.

I recommend to use a key manager like Metamask, on the contrary, you will need to expose your keys to sign the transactions.

Comment: OK - but I AM using Metamask. I'm currently logged into the Rinkeby Testnet through my Metamask (using Chrome.)  Isn't that what I should be doing?

Comment: Metamask is not injecting web3, that is why you have: ""1. NO Web3 provider found!  Gonna set one up..." in the console. Check that metamask is unlocked.

Comment: just to make sure, when you say " Check that metamask is unlocked" - you mean that I'm signed into my account? Or is there some other "unlocking" that I have to do that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the check for `MetaMask` injection is an asynchronous type of event.  Cause everytime I've tested this, I HAVE been logged into `MetaMask` - but its clearly not recognizing that fact, and it immediately proceeds to the `else` part of my logic and tries to go via `infura`...

Comment: just to sign into your account. Check the new proposed method to log in after nov 2 [here](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8)

Comment: looking into it...

Comment: still not working...

Comment: what did you do?. Take into consideration that your html should be served by a server for metamask to work. just opening your html file won't do.